# Why am I facing this Problem in Arduino when connecting Firebase?

Tags: firebase, arduino

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled (new aborts on oom), Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 32KB cache + 32KB IRAM (balanced), Use pgm_read macros for IRAM/PROGMEM, 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseObject.cpp: In member function 'bool FirebaseObject::isNullString(const String&) const':

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseObject.cpp:71:57: warning: 'const char* ArduinoJson::Internals::JsonVariantCasts<TImpl>::asString() const [with TImpl = ArduinoJson::JsonVariant]' is deprecated: use as<char*>() instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

   71 |   return variant.is<const char *>() && variant.asString() == NULL;

      |                                                         ^

In file included from c:\users\jordan\documents\arduino\libraries\arduinojson\src\arduinojson\JsonVariantBase.hpp:7,

                 from c:\users\jordan\documents\arduino\libraries\arduinojson\src\arduinojson\JsonVariant.hpp:13,

                 from c:\users\jordan\documents\arduino\libraries\arduinojson\src\arduinojson\jsonbuffer.hpp:12,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Deserialization/JsonParser.hpp:7,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/JsonBufferBase.hpp:7,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/DynamicJsonBuffer.hpp:7,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson.hpp:9,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson.h:9,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseObject.h:24,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseObject.cpp:17:

c:\users\jordan\documents\arduino\libraries\arduinojson\src\arduinojson\JsonVariantCasts.hpp:28:28: note: declared here

   28 |   FORCE_INLINE const char *asString() const {

      |                            ^~~~~~~~

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseObject.cpp: In member function 'ArduinoJson::JsonVariant FirebaseObject::getJsonVariant(const String&) const':

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseObject.cpp:91:26: warning: 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject& ArduinoJson::Internals::JsonVariantCasts<TImpl>::asObject() const [with TImpl = ArduinoJson::JsonVariant]' is deprecated: use as<JsonObject>() instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

   91 |     json = json.asObject().get<JsonVariant>(start);

      |                          ^

In file included from c:\users\jordan\documents\arduino\libraries\arduinojson\src\arduinojson\JsonVariantBase.hpp:7,

                 from c:\users\jordan\documents\arduino\libraries\arduinojson\src\arduinojson\JsonVariant.hpp:13,

                 from c:\users\jordan\documents\arduino\libraries\arduinojson\src\arduinojson\jsonbuffer.hpp:12,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/Deserialization/JsonParser.hpp:7,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/JsonBufferBase.hpp:7,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson/DynamicJsonBuffer.hpp:7,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson.hpp:9,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson\src/ArduinoJson.h:9,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseObject.h:24,

                 from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseObject.cpp:17:

c:\users\jordan\documents\arduino\libraries\arduinojson\src\arduinojson\JsonVariantCasts.hpp:23:28: note: declared here

   23 |   FORCE_INLINE JsonObject &asObject() const {

      |                            ^~~~~~~~

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\Firebase.cpp: In member function 'int FirebaseRequest::sendRequest(const string&, const string&, char*, const string&, const string&)':

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\Firebase.cpp:78:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

   78 | }

      | ^

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\Firebase.cpp: In member function 'void FirebaseStream::startStreaming(const string&, const string&, const string&)':

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\Firebase.cpp:91:16: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

   91 |   analyzeError("STREAM", status, path_with_auth);

      |                ^~~~~~~~

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseArduino.cpp: In member function 'String FirebaseArduino::push(const String&, const ArduinoJson::JsonVariant&)':

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseArduino.cpp:65:54: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

   65 |   int status = req_.get()->sendRequest(host_, auth_, "POST", path.c_str(), buf);

      |                                                      ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseArduino.cpp: In member function 'void FirebaseArduino::set(const String&, const ArduinoJson::JsonVariant&)':

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseArduino.cpp:94:41: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

   94 |   req_.get()->sendRequest(host_, auth_, "PUT", path.c_str(), buf);

      |                                         ^~~~~

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseArduino.cpp: In member function 'void FirebaseArduino::getRequest(const String&)':

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseArduino.cpp:101:41: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

  101 |   req_.get()->sendRequest(host_, auth_, "GET", path.c_str());

      |                                         ^~~~~

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseArduino.cpp: In member function 'virtual void FirebaseArduino::remove(const String&)':

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseArduino.cpp:147:41: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

  147 |   req_.get()->sendRequest(host_, auth_, "DELETE", path.c_str());

      |                                         ^~~~~~~~

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseArduino.cpp: In member function 'virtual const String& FirebaseArduino::error()':

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseArduino.cpp:201:32: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]

  201 |   return error_.message().c_str();

      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp: In member function 'virtual void FirebaseHttpClientEsp8266::begin(const string&)':

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:50: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(const char*, const char [60])'

   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);

      |                                                  ^

In file included from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:

C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:166:10: note: candidate: 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, uint16_t, String)' (near match)

  166 |     bool begin(String host, uint16_t port, String uri = "/")  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, host, port, uri)")));

      |          ^~~~~

C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:166:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} [-fpermissive]

   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);

      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      |                              |

      |                              const char*

In file included from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:

C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:167:10: note: candidate: 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, const uint8_t*)' (near match)

  167 |     bool begin(String url, const uint8_t httpsFingerprint[20])  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClientSecure, ...)")));

      |          ^~~~~

C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:167:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} [-fpermissive]

   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);

      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      |                              |

      |                              const char*

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp: In member function 'virtual void FirebaseHttpClientEsp8266::begin(const string&, const string&)':

C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:51:60: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} [-fpermissive]

   51 |     http_.begin(host.c_str(), kFirebasePort, path.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);

      |                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      |                                                            |

      |                                                            const char*

In file included from C:\Users\Jordan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:

C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:168:70: note:   initializing argument 4 of 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, uint16_t, String, const uint8_t*)'

  168 |     bool begin(String host, uint16_t port, String uri, const uint8_t httpsFingerprint[20])  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClientSecure, ...)")));

      |                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

exit status 1

Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the mistakes as I was transferring the code from an old laptop to a new laptop.

Guess What? The  version of Arduino library that i recently download in my new laptop does not match the version in the old laptop!
That is why the error message had pop out.

Answer (score 2):

When I faced the same issue, I rolled back to 2.7.4 on the board manager, which result in it compiling without a problem. I guess the board software updated before the FireBase library did. I found this solution on [this page](https://www.gitmemory.com/jamesdaniels).

Comment: With respect to the link you are using, it would be better to link to the actual issue in the repository, rather than a summary of participation, which is likely to not contain the information about this issue at some point in the future (i.e. when other, newer, participation by that user pushes it off that list).

Answer (score 0):

with platformio, change in platformio.ini (work for me), for latest 2.x version:

> platform = espressif8266@^2

[Solution from this page](https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif8266/releases/tag/v3.0.0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

rolled back to 2.7.X version[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWZ4p.png)

Comment: You are trying to say thanks for the other answers which proposed to solve by rolling back, aren't you? Otherwise please make more obvious what addtional insight you contribute please.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).